# google maps touch listener not working in recyclerview android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places

I have implemented google maps inside RecyclerView. I'm trying to implement both the Places API functionality and google maps both to be on the same activity. The problem is the Places Api is working fine but the google maps interface is unresponsive. When I try to zoom in the google map or click on it there is no response, it is static.

Below is my code:

```
public class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter.PredictionHolder> implements Filterable {

    private static final String TAG = "PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter";
    private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> mResultList;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LatLngBounds mBounds;
    private AutocompleteFilter mPlaceFilter;

    private Context mContext;
    private int layout;

    public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int resource, GoogleApiClient googleApiClient,
                                     LatLngBounds bounds, AutocompleteFilter filter) {
        mContext = context;
        layout = resource;
        mGoogleApiClient = googleApiClient;
        mBounds = bounds;
        mPlaceFilter = filter;
    }

    public void setBounds(LatLngBounds bounds) {
        mBounds = bounds;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                if (constraint != null) {

                    mResultList = getAutocomplete(constraint);
                    if (mResultList != null) {
                        results.values = mResultList;
                        results.count = mResultList.size();
                    }
                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {

                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }

    private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> getAutocomplete(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Log.i("", "Starting autocomplete query for: " + constraint);


            PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
                    Places.GeoDataApi
                            .getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(),
                                    mBounds, mPlaceFilter);
thread. Block and wait for at most 60s

            AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions = results
                    .await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            final Status status = autocompletePredictions.getStatus();
            if (!status.isSuccess()) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error contacting API: " + status.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("", "Error getting autocomplete prediction API call: " + status.toString());
                autocompletePredictions.release();
                return null;
            }

            Log.i("", "Query completed. Received " + autocompletePredictions.getCount()
                    + " predictions.");


            Iterator<AutocompletePrediction> iterator = autocompletePredictions.iterator();
            ArrayList resultList = new ArrayList<>(autocompletePredictions.getCount());
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                AutocompletePrediction prediction = iterator.next();

                resultList.add(new PlaceAutocomplete(prediction.getPlaceId(),
                        prediction.getDescription()));
            }
            autocompletePredictions.release();

            return resultList;
        }
        Log.e("", "Google API client is not connected for autocomplete query.");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public PredictionHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, viewGroup, false);
        PredictionHolder mPredictionHolder = new PredictionHolder(convertView);
        return mPredictionHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PredictionHolder mPredictionHolder, final int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(mResultList != null)
            return mResultList.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public PlaceAutocomplete getItem(int position) {
        return mResultList.get(position);
    }

    public class PredictionHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView mPrediction;
        private RelativeLayout mRow;
        public PredictionHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            mPrediction = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.address);
            mRow=(RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.predictedRow);
        }

    }

    public void clear() {
        mResultList.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class PlaceAutocomplete {

        public CharSequence placeId;
        public CharSequence description;

        PlaceAutocomplete(CharSequence placeId, CharSequence description) {
            this.placeId = placeId;
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return description.toString();
        }
    }


}


public class PlacesAutoCompleteActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        View.OnClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback,
        LocationListener {
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private boolean executeOnStart = false;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    MarkerOptions markerOptions;
    private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_INDIA = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(-0, 0), new LatLng(0, 0));
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    private String mapAddress = null;
    private StringBuilder sb = null;
    private EditText mAutocompleteView;
    private Geocoder geocoder;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
    private PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter mAutoCompleteAdapter;
    PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item;
    String featureName, locality, countryName;
    String placeId;
    ImageView delete;
    private LatLng pos;
    static boolean invalidLocation = false; // this value confirms whether we are able to deliver to users location
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        mAutocompleteView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_places);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(PlacesAutoCompleteActivity.this);

        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        delete = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cross);

        mAutoCompleteAdapter = new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.searchview_adapter,
                mGoogleApiClient, BOUNDS_INDIA, null);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAutoCompleteAdapter);
        delete.setOnClickListener(this);
        mAutocompleteView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                      int count) {
                if (!s.toString().equals("") && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    mAutoCompleteAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                } else if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Constants.API_NOT_CONNECTED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e(Constants.PlacesTag, Constants.API_NOT_CONNECTED);
                }

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        item = mAutoCompleteAdapter.getItem(position);
                        placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);

                        PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                                .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
                        placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                                if (places.getCount() == 1) {
                                    mAutoCompleteAdapter.clear();
                                    mAutocompleteView.setText("");
                                    String country = "";

                                    try {
                                        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(places.get(0).getLatLng().latitude,
                                                places.get(0).getLatLng().longitude, 1);
                                        sb = new StringBuilder();
                                        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                                            android.location.Address address = addresses.get(0);

                                            featureName = address.getFeatureName();
                                            locality = address.getLocality();
                                            countryName = address.getCountryName();


                                            Log.d("featureName ",  featureName + "||" +
                                                    locality +"||" + countryName);
                                            if (featureName == null) {
                                                mapAddress = address.getLocality() + " " + address.getCountryName();
                                            } else if (locality == null) {
                                                mapAddress = address.getFeatureName() + ", " + address.getCountryName();
                                            } else if (countryName == null) {
                                                mapAddress = address.getFeatureName() + ", " + address.getLocality();
                                            } else {
                                                mapAddress = address.getFeatureName() + ", " + address.getLocality() + " " + address.getCountryName();
                                                country = address.getCountryName();
                                                Log.d("counttryy", "sasa"+country);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        Log.d("mpaddress", "kaka "+mapAddress + "||" + country);

                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    //Do the things here on Click.....
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello {}" +countryName+"{}"+featureName+"{}"+"{}"+ String.valueOf(places.get(0).getLatLng()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                            .target(places.get(0).getLatLng())      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
                                            .zoom(12)                   // Sets the zoom
                                            .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                                            .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                                            .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
                                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(places.get(0).getLatLng())
                                            .title("My Location"));
                                    mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
                                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Constants.SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        Log.i("TAG", "Clicked: " + item.description);
                        Log.i("TAG", "Called getPlaceById to get Place details for " + item.placeId);
                    }
                })
        );

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YOOOOOO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
             mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation = location;

        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }
        LatLng latLng = null;
        final Double lat = location.getLatitude();
        final Double lng = location.getLongitude();
        Log.d("LATLANG", lat + "|" + lng);
        LatLng latLng2 = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions2 = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions2.position(latLng);
        markerOptions2.title("Current Positionn");
        markerOptions2.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng2));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));


        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }


        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                android.location.Address address = addresses.get(0);

                String featureName = address.getFeatureName();
                String locality = address.getLocality();
                String countryName = address.getCountryName();

                System.out.println("featureName " + featureName + "||" + locality +"||" + countryName);
                if (featureName == null) {
                    mapAddress = address.getLocality() + " " + address.getCountryName();
                } else if (locality == null) {
                    mapAddress = address.getFeatureName() + ", " + address.getCountryName();
                } else if (countryName == null) {
                    mapAddress = address.getFeatureName() + ", " + address.getLocality();
                } else {
                    mapAddress = address.getFeatureName() + ", " + address.getLocality() + " " + address.getCountryName();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("mpaddress " + mapAddress + "||" );

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latlng) {
            }
        });
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.v("Google API Callback", "Connection Suspended");
        Log.v("Code", String.valueOf(i));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.v("Google API Callback","Connection Failed");
        Log.v("Error Code", String.valueOf(connectionResult.getErrorCode()));
        Toast.makeText(this, Constants.API_NOT_CONNECTED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d("permission","permission");
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


            } else {
                Log.d("permission2","permission2");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            }
        }
    }

}
```